# Xamarin android - OutOfMemory at creating bitmaps and setting to ImageView in view pager

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I've started recently to play around with Xamarin-Android and discovered that when you use a `ViewPager` with an `ImageView` and `Bitmap` an `OutOfMemoryError` will occur very fast.

I've created [2 small test apps](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/OOMTest-projects), which only have the goal to show this behaviour. One app is programmed with Xamarin in `C#`, the other one is an usual android project in `Java`. Both apps contain a `ViewPager` with 20 pages (fragments). The `Fragment` again contains an `ImageView` which gets a red coloured `Bitmap` set:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.RED);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now swipe through the pages and look at the *Android Studio Memory Monitor*. If you compare both apps you will notice that the usual android app behaves as expected, the memory usage stays at a certain MB amount. On the other hand the memory of the Xamarin app increases with every page swipe until an `OutOfMemorError` occurs.

So my question now is why this happens and how I can prevent the `OutOfMemoryError`?

I've tried to create the `Bitmap` like the following, but that didn't help:

```
using(var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888)) {
    bitmap.EraseColor(Color.Red);
    mImageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Also some bitmap recycling and other stuff in the `OnStop()` method didn't change anything:

```
public override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
    ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.Drawable).Bitmap.Recycle();
    ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.Drawable).Bitmap.Dispose();
    mImageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
    mImageView.Dispose();
}
```

Do you have any suggestions what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the only solution for the problem I could find is to invoke the garbage collection manually in the `OnStop()` method like this:

```
GC.Collect();
```

I don't like the approach very much, but it does the job and doesn't seem to cause any other problems.